# How to make a file with .pt extension, with xml syntax highlighting and vim's plugin snipmate load pt.snippets?

Tags: xml, vim, plugins, zpt, snipmate

I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pt set filetype=xml
```

This is needed because although I'm editing a file with `*.pt` extension, it's indeed a valid xml file: setting the filetype like this I can have syntax highlighting.

I'm using [vim's snipmate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), and tried to create pt.snippets to specific needs since these files are Zope Page Templates (ZPT with TAL).

Now, I have a problem: I don't want to create these snippets in xml.snippets, since they aren't really generic xml snippets, but my `*.pt` files are set to xml, so when I define my pt snippets they aren't loaded unless I run `:set filetype=pt` on my pt file on vim - but then I lose syntax highlighting.

I would like to be able to have a pt file, with xml syntax highlighting, to be able to load a pt.snippets file from snipmate. How can I do it?

(I would like to avoid putting my snippets in a generic snippet file, I would like it to be present only in pt.snippets to be easier to maintain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snipmate allows for dotted 'filetype' syntax, try:

> au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pt set filetype=xml.pt

Answer (score 3):

the syntax is notoriously finnicky for not wanting to support two concurrent filetypes (actually, someone asked this same question yesterday)

```
au BufRead *.pt set filetype=xml.pt
au BufNewFile *.pt set filetype=xml.pt
```

jinfield's answer is actually spot-on, but I have had the comma-syntax fail on some versions of vim

Comment: sleepynate, thanks for answering. Strange enough, jinfields answer is working!! Don't know why it wasn't before, I think I did something wrong... thanks anyway for your comma-syntax suggestion.

Comment: Yea, no problem. I have had the same issue with it failing when wanting to use both php and html snippets in CakePHP templates.

Answer (score 1):

How about?:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pt setlocal filetype=pt
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pt setlocal syntax=xml
```

Comment: "setlocal" doesn't work, but doing "autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pt set filetype=pt" works. Can you explain why?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you.  The above 'autocmd's along with a very simple `pt.snippets` seem to be working for me (Vim 7.2, snipMate 0.83).  If you run the above commands (just the "setlocal..." part) by hand, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works... but strange enough, I have a colorscheme named "molokai". When I run the first command (filetype=pt), it loses the colorscheme. When I run "syntax=xml", it recovers a colorscheme, but instead of molokai I think it gets the standard vim xml syntax.