# Vim verbosefile with timestamps

Tags: vim

I have a number of very long and complex Vim configuration files, but these seem to be causing some unpredictable performance slowdowns.

Is there a way of producing a logfile of Vim's internal activity (in the style of `verbosefile`) which also includes timestamps for each function call to allow me to debug these issues. Alternatively, are there any other tools to help me in this task?

Comment: Although not particularly useful for measuring runtime (because `timer_start` can be delayed while running intensive code), you can still use `timer_start` + `strftime` to `echo` out contents to the verbosefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is invoking vim with `--startuptime some_file`. This will dump the steps performed during startup, along with timestamps. Try `:help --startuptime` for some more information.

Unfortunately, this shows you timestamps for files, not functions. If you want to see how long a specific function takes, you could put a call to it in a file under the `plugin` directory, so it's executed on boot. This won't be possible in all cases and it won't give you a lot of granularity, but it might help you narrow down the problem. Someone else might have a better idea, but I'd start by trying something like this.

**EDIT**:

I just found two things that may help with this problem. One of them is `reltime()`. Here's an example from vim's help:

```
let start = reltime()
call MyFunction()
echo reltimestr(reltime(start))
```

All it does is show the time a function takes to execute. Combined with, for example, [Decho](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=120), this could provide a simple log of said functions.

The second one should be a lot more powerfule, the `:profile` command. It lets you profile a piece of vimscript and place the results in a file. [:help profile](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3aprofile) should tell you all you need to know. Unfortunately, it's only available with the `+profile` feature, which seems to be enabled only in the "huge" feature set. If your vim doesn't have it, you'll need to recompile. If that's a problem, or you don't want to bother, you might be able to achieve good results with `reltime` alone.

Comment: Thanks, these are good tips, but unfortunately the performance issues I am experiencing do not occur at startup.

Comment: I found another possibility for you to try, `reltime` and `:profile`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If --startuptime does not fit your needs, you may use the following command:

```
vim --cmd 'profile start profile.log' \ 
    --cmd 'profile func *' \ 
    --cmd 'profile file *' \ 
    -c 'profile pause' \ 
    -c 'qa!'
```

(replace `--cmd` with `-c` and add `-c 'Command that causes slowdown'` if problem occurs not at startup). You will get all timings in the profile.log. Table with function timings will be present at the end of the file, to get per-script timings, use the following 
script:

```
" Open profile.log file in vim first 
let timings=[] 
g/^SCRIPT/call add(timings, [getline('.')[len('SCRIPT  '):], matchstr(getline(line('.')+1), '^Sourced \zs\d\+')]+map(getline(line('.')+2, line('.')+3), 'matchstr(v:val, ''\d\+\.\d\+$'')')) 
enew 
call setline('.', ['count total (s)   self (s)  script']+map(copy(timings), 'printf("%5u %9s   %8s  %s", v:val[1], v:val[2], v:val[3], v:val[0])'))
```

This will open a new file containing just the same table as at the end of profile.log, but 1) for scripts, not for functions, 2) unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never?  I was searching to see if I could get vim to include some timestamps in the `&verbosefile`, as it causes vim to append to the file with no indication of when the appending started.

I adapted the solution from [ZyX's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log/3026047#3026047) and after trying some things out, found that a simple `echo "foo\n"` will append `foo` and a newline to the `&verbosefile`:

```
let s:VerboseLS = ' **** V'.'E'.'RB'.'OSE LO'.'GG'.'ING S'.'TA'.'RTED ****'
let s:VerboseLE = ' **** V'.'E'.'RB'.'OSE LO'.'GG'.'ING E'.'ND'.'ED ****'
function! ToggleVerbose()
    let l:timestamp = strftime("%c")
    if !&verbose
      let l:msg = "\n\n" . l:timestamp . s:VerboseLS . "\n\n"
      set verbosefile=~/.vim/log/verbose.log
      set verbose=100
      echo l:msg
    else
      let l:msg = "\n" . l:timestamp . s:VerboseLE . "\n"
      echo l:msg
      set verbose=0
      set verbosefile=
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>vl :call ToggleVerbose()<CR>
```

Now I get nice banners in my log:

```
Sun Feb 17 14:18:02 2013 **** VERBOSE LOGGING STARTED ****

...[snip]...

Sun Feb 17 14:18:08 2013 **** VERBOSE LOGGING ENDED ****
```

I defined those banners the way I did so that if I source that script file while verbose logging is on so if I search the log for "VERBOSE LOGGING" or similar I won't match on them.

So, you could adapt this method to use `reltime` if your vim `has('reltime')` for sub-second precision and maybe make a timing wrapper to `call` that echos the start/end times for function calls (although you'd have to refactor when you call things inline without the `call` command).

Ooh, I just had an idea... I wonder if `&verbosefile` can be set to a named pipe that goes to util that prepends time stamps... Let's see...

Comment: Darn... I *can* have vim write to a named pipe for `&verbosefile`, but it appears to be buffering output as if it were writing to a filesystem file, so my idea to prepend timestamps from the pipe won't work. :/