# Debugging Vim plugins with call traces

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What is the preferable, general method of debugging/tracing vim plugins ? Suppose I have got a fairly sophisticated plugin Foo, which on a key pressed <kbd>F9</kbd> opens new window with file-browser and gives the possibility to choose a file, after that the filename is copied into the main window. I would like to see what is called when I press the <kbd>F9</kbd> key, some kind of call trace.

Comment: See also: [Is there a "vim runtime log"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way I have found is to use the `-V` flag when starting (g)vim. You can specify a level of tracing `N` and a filename for the written log:

```
$ vim -V[N]{filename}
```

Then trace messages will be given for each file that is sourced. (See `:help -V` for more info.)

Trawling through the resulting logfile can be painful, but it is usually pretty informative. I find it best to view the logfile before and after the trigger event (pressing `<F9>` in your case) to get a picture of when is happening.

Comment: In my case, the syntax was: `vim -V[insert number] [insert filename]` - for example `vim -V20 filename.txt`

Comment: See `:help 'verbose'`.

Comment: See `:help 'verbose'` for the meaning of the levels. Unfortunately there's no way to prevent the buffering of the log file (see `:help 'verbosefile'`), and it isn't possible to add timestamp either ([Vim verbosefile with timestamps - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091224/vim-verbosefile-with-timestamps))

Answer (score 7):

If you already have vim open, try executing the command manually under VIM's built in debugger.

1) Find out what vim does when you press the key

```
:map <F-9>
```

2) Run the mapped command manually under debugger

```
:debug _mapped_command_
```

3) Right now you should be dropped in to the debugger, so

```
set verbose=20
```

4) And finally press `n` and Enter key to continue running the script

At this point you should see a whole bunch of output on the screen. You can press Space to scroll the screen, j/k to move by line.

Any output that starts with "Line #:" is the line vim is executing at that time.

Comment: To set a breakpoint while in debug mode, use `:breaka[dd] func [lnum] {name}` or `:breaka[dd] file [lnum] {name}`. To set a conditional breakpoint, modify the script to include an if-statement with your condition, put a no-op inside the if-statement (like `let xyz = 1`), and use `breakadd` to add a breakpoint on the no-op line. (See `:help breakadd`.) Then type `cont` or `c` to continue execution until the breakpoint line is executed.

Answer (score 1):

For sophisticated plugins, normally command line debugging or tracing is not enough.

You can use [BreakPts](https://github.com/albfan/vim-breakpts) to do a visual debug inside vim.

It is based on remote debugging, so you need to debug a server instance of vim.

Basically:

Terminal 1:

```
$ vim --servername Foo
...
set breakpoint on any Foo function
do whatever operation which trigger Foo logic
...
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ vim
:BreakPts
:BPRemoteServ FOO
:BPDWhere locate (actual debug execution point)
:BPDNext or F12 (next execution line)
:BPDStep or F11 (step inside functions, dictionary functions)
:BPDEvaluate or F8 (if pressed on visual selection evaluates that)
:BPDCont or F5 (continue execution)
```

See some plugins are loaded dinamically so you need to operate with them prior to set breakpoints.

Once loaded you can set breakpoints from connected vim with:

```
:BPFunctions (Show debuggeable fuctions on RemoteServer)
:BPScripts (Show debuggeable scripts on RemoteServer)
:BPPoints (Show defined breakpoints on RemoteServer)
```

I have fix/tweak/evolve a lot of vim plugins thanks to this great plugin.