# Explore and debug vim script

Tags: debugging, vim

I would like to dynamically debug a vim script. My current workflow is that I have the autoload plugin opened on a tmux pannel and the running application on the other pannel. I also set a `tail -f vim.log` and I launched vim with `vim -V15vim.log`. My goal is to monitor the execution of the plugin by adding plenty of `echom`.

Actually I was expecting something more useful that what I actually got.

- I need to restart vim everytime I add a new `echom`
- Nothing really useful is displayed on the log file `vim.log`
- This method is obviously not the right one

I also tried to add breakpoints with `breakadd func myfunc#test` but it is not really working because the debugger windows interfers with the main window and change the way the plugin I am debuging behave.

How to improve my vim-script debug workflow?

**HINT**

I am actually trying to debug the `vim-multiple-cursor` plugin which does not work with a column block selection and virtualedit enabled. I would like to fix it.

Comment: See also: [Debugging Vim plugins with call traces - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656429/debugging-vim-plugins-with-call-traces#comments-9668599)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:breakadd` is the most powerful tool, but yes, its output and interaction may interfere with certain plugin actions, and trigger additional autocmds. It may help if you specify the optional `[lnum]` offset to only stop executing inside the function.

> I need to restart vim everytime I add a new `echom`

It should be enough if you just `:source` the changed plugin script again. Scripts inside `~/.vim/plugin/` usually employ a multiple inclusion guard that you need to work around, though. My [ReloadScript plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1904) can help with that.

Alternatively, the [Decho plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=120) might offer a different approach worth looking at.