# Error message when Vim is closed

Tags: vim

I am tweaking my vimrc but everytime when I close Vim I can see that there is a red error message displayed. However, Vim closes too fast so I cannot read it.

Is there any way to get to that error message using the latest Vim on Windows 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a "vim runtime log"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log)

Comment: Indeed, sorry for that. I found the possible solution in the other thread by running vim.bat -V9errorlog in the Windows Power Shell

Comment: Can you isolate it to a particular part of your .vimrc?

Comment: If it solved your problem then you should then either vote to close this thread as a duplicate of that one or delete your question entirely or post your solution as an answer below. Whichever you feel is appropriate.

Comment: Just a thought: Can  you use the VimLeave event to write the v:errmsg variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your _vimrc, ... do stuff ..., source it with `:so %` - the message should be displayed, and you should be able to see it in `:messages`.

If it is only occuring when you close Vim, even with an empty _vimrc, then it isn't a problem in your _vimrc.

Comment: That's also a nice one. Thank you for that!

Regards

Answer (score 5):

I found the possible solution in the other thread by running vim.bat -V9errorlog in the Windows Power Shell.