# snipMate only working on empty buffer?

Tags: vim, snipmate

I'm attempting to use snipMate with sql files, however it doesn't seem to work when editing an existing file.

If I create a new empty buffer (no file; e.g. launch gvim from the start menu), and set the filetype to `sql` (`:set ft=sql`), it works.  However, if I then try to open a sql file (e.g. `:e c:\blah.sql`) and edit it, snipMate no longer works.  What gives!?

**Setup:**

- gvim
- vim 7.3
- Windows 7
- snipMate 0.84
- Also, I do in fact have `filetype plugin on` in my `.vimrc` file.

**edit**

Apparently if I open an empty buffer, set the filetype to sql, then save to file using `w c:\blah.sql`, I now have a sql file open AND snipMate continues to work.

**edit**

Here's a gist of my current .vimrc in case it helps: https://gist.github.com/3946877

Comment: So when you do `:set filetype?` you get `sql`?

Comment: @romainl Just ran `:set filetype?`, response `filetype=sql`

Comment: where do you have your `filetype plugin on` in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @gokcehan It's currently the 4th item from the top, and I have ~50 non-comment lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your `.vimrc` on my computer and it works fine. There's a `filetype.vim` file in `$VIMRUNTIME` which detects filetypes on startup and most likely you have some problem within that file. These are the relevant lines from mine:

```
" SQL
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sql         call s:SQL()

func! s:SQL()
  if exists("g:filetype_sql")
    exe "setf " . g:filetype_sql
  else
    setf sql
  endif
endfunc
```

You can copy these to `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` or just to your `.vimrc` and that should solve the problem but then again you shouldn't have this problem in the first place.

Let me know how you progress..

**NOTE** `$VIMRUNTIME` is `/usr/share/vim/vim73` in my machine, you can find yours by running `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` in a vim session

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Bummer though, as it still is not working.  I think I'm going to try to reinstall/etc tonight, and see if the issue persists.  Are there vim logs that I can look at to see if there are any errors/warnings when my vim is run?  That might help me see if there's something wrong with my setup.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like vim doesn't recognize the sql filetype from the extension. Try putting this into your .vimrc:

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,Bufnewfile *.sql setfiletype sql
augroup END
```

Comment: It's not clear from the comments whether the OP checked this before setting the filetype manually.

Answer (score 0):

Uggggh, I'm an idiot!

I decided to remove all plugins except snipMate, and then I slowly added my plugins back in. I didn't realize it when I was hooking up snipMate, but I had already added a plugin previously for doing code completion called [code complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1764).  Apparently this nerd and snipMate were at war, so once I removed code complete snipMate miraculously began to work!

Hopefully this might help someone in the future.