# Command-T exits vim whenever <leader> t is pressed

Tags: vim

I'm using Command-T on an ubuntu machine and it's freaking out.  When I press `<leader> t`, it will exit VIM, and then totally change the allignment of my screen (Text just appears indented in strange an usual ways).

To fix this, I opend up my .vimrc file and mapped command-T to f.

```
map <silent> <LocalLeader>f :CommandT<CR>
```

But it doesn't change the behavior--i.e. when I press `<leader> t`, Vim shuts down and the terminal window will display weird indentation for the rest of my session.

When I say that VIM shuts down, I mean that I'm exited from the program abruptly, but without any error message being thrown.

My system details are as follows:

- VMware Fusion 6 running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, release 12.04, Precise
- zshell 4.3.17
- VIM 7.3
- tmux 1.6

Comment: What other plugins do you have enabled? Is it possible that something else is mapped to `<leader>t`?

Comment: Try `:verb map <leader>t` to see what's setting that.

Comment: When I run `:verb map`, I get ' \t :CommandD <CR> Last set from ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Try running just `:CommandD` and see if that's closing vim as well. Looks like it may be the problem. Look into that function or share its source.

Comment: Sorry--typo. :verb map <leader>t, gives me' \t :CommandT<CR>.Last set from ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

The fact, that your mapping with `<Leader> f` works and `<Leader> t` doesn't might point that this is not a Vim issue.

I would suggest getting a runtine log from Vim (See [Is there a "vim runtime log"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log)) and analyzing it.