# Identify which vim plugin is causing behavior

Tags: vim

I'm seeing some visual artifacts on left margin for vim and nvim. I'm not sure which plugin is causing this behaviour. I've tried enable / disable some combinations of plugin but can't identify.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The command `scriptnames` show all sourced script names. Look for scripts that alter highlighting. Once you identify the culprit script you could disable it or fix it.

Comment: Probably ale or syntastic

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log

Answer (score 2):

You can find exactly what the definition is using `:sign list`. This can help you find out what plugin they are defined in. (`:help signs`, `:help :sign-list`)

Unfortunately it seems that `:sign` does not work with `:verbose`, so you're on your own about finding where the definition is. Other people already mentioned `:scriptnames`, but maybe it might be as simple as `grep -r sign .vim/plugged` (replace with whatever directory houses your plugins).

Answer (score 1):

As Sergio said, you can see all files that *could* have that highlight rule with `:scriptnames`. There is no way to determine which file in particular is causing it from vim. You'll have the best luck disabling everything and adding them in groups until the behavior comes back. You could read through all the files and try to find it that way, but I wouldn't recommend it.

`vim <file> -u NONE` will load vim without your `.vimrc` if you want to validate that a clean environment will not have this issue. Then you can try your `.vimrc` with no plugins, and then start adding in plugins (in groups, if you have a ton of plugins) to determine which one is at fault.