# Mysterious vim context popup: where is it coming from, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

### Update: started with new config & much better now

I made a lot of changes to my vim setup recently. One of them seems to come with a popup providing context when I hover over a class, string, function, etc. for a few seconds. I can't for the life of me track down which plugin is doing this -- does anyone know?

[image]

Here is the full config, minus some definitely-unrelated-lines to get it below the limit for stackoverflow to let me post this:

```
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" Pathogen 
execute pathogen#infect()

" jsdoc
nmap <silent> <C-l> <Plug>(jsdoc)
let g:jsdoc_allow_input_prompt = 1
let g:jsdoc_input_description = 1
let g:jsdoc_enable_es6 = 1
let g:javascript_plugin_jsdoc = 1

let g:javascript_conceal_function       = "ƒ"
let g:javascript_conceal_null           = "ø"
let g:javascript_conceal_this           = "@"
let g:javascript_conceal_return         = "⇚"
let g:javascript_conceal_undefined      = "¿"
let g:javascript_conceal_NaN            = "ℕ"
let g:javascript_conceal_prototype      = "¶"
let g:javascript_conceal_static         = "•"
let g:javascript_conceal_super          = "Ω"
let g:javascript_conceal_arrow_function = "⇒"

" enable omnicomplete
" set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete

set ignorecase " Ignore case when searching
set smartcase " When searching try to be smart about cases
set hlsearch " Highlight search resultsh
set incsearch " be like search in modern browsers

" Spellcheck en_CA
nnoremap <C-w>s :setlocal spell spelllang=en_ca<CR>
nnoremap <C-w>S :setlocal nospell<CR>

 " reselect visual block after indent
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" VUNDLE: 
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'supertab'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" GIST:
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" gist-vim
let g:gist_detect_filetype = 1
let g:gist_post_private = 1

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" NERDTree:
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" open when vim opens
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

" open when C-n
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

let g:loaded_netrw       = 1
let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Airline:
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" tabline enabled
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 0

" use powerline fonts
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

" show status line all the time
set laststatus=2

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" PLUG:
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Ternjs: run `npm install` the first time
" .dotfiles/vim.symlink/plugged/tern_for_vim

"Plug 'benmills/vimux' 
"Plug 'geekjuice/vim-mocha'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'chrisbra/csv.vim'
Plug 'chriskempson/base16-vim'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plug 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'
Plug 'ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim'
Plug 'elzr/vim-json'
"Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
"Plug 'esneider/YUNOcommit.vim'
Plug 'heavenshell/vim-jsdoc'
Plug 'ivalkeen/vim-ctrlp-tjump'
Plug 'jasoncodes/ctrlp-modified.vim'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
"Plug 'jlanzarotta/bufexplorer'
"Plug 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
"Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
"Plug 'maksimr/vim-jsbeautify'
"Plug 'marcweber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plug 'mattn/gist-vim'
Plug 'mattn/webapi-vim'
Plug 'mileszs/ack.vim'
Plug 'moll/vim-node'
Plug 'othree/yajs.vim'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
"Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
"Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'sgur/ctrlp-extensions.vim'
Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
Plug 'sjl/gundo.vim'
Plug 'suan/vim-instant-markdown'
"Plug 'takac/vim-spotifysearch'
"Plug 'ternjs/tern_for_vim'
"Plug 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
"Plug 'tpope/vim-abolish'
"Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
"Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'vim-scripts/winresizer.vim'
"Plug 'xolox/vim-easytags'
"Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'
```

Comment: This is pretty hopeless without you listing your config.

Comment: Fair enough -- done!

Comment: your config is extremely broken. Throw it away, delete your .vim directory and start over. You have plugin installs outside of `vundle#begin()` and `vundle#end()`, you have a lot of stuff that _isn’t_ plugin stuff between those two, you use _both_ pathogen _and_ vundle...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811835/identify-which-vim-plugin-is-causing-behavior/