# nvim unexpected exit, looking for logs

Tags: ubuntu, neovim

Sometimes, when I am deleting some lines, such as `20dd` or `ddG`, vim closes unexpectedly.

I don't know why and I can't add more info because I don't know where to look at. Is there any kind of log?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the log generated by nvim on `$HOME/.cache/nvim/log`.
Each line shows the log level and error message. Check if there are any errors when nvim exited.

Comment: at the end I had to use (if I remember correctly), this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3026047/13182570, but I see some errors in that file, next time I'll check there first.
Do you know if there's some difference between the logs I saw in both cases (your answer and the one I found)

Comment: I think log in `$HOME/.cache/nvim/log` only logs serious issues. Log in that answer will print a lot of unnecessary messages if you have a high verbose level.

Comment: Anyone know where to find this on Windows?

Comment: @Cogwheel Did you ever found out?

Comment: @Sid I found the log file under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\nvim-data`

Comment: @Cogwheel Oh I eventually found out too. Thanks anyways